# SwiftUI re-render code inside for loop after @State chage

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wrote a small program in this gist https://gist.github.com/alfonsodev/411622f65727bd5f44eff13f6e7e0a9b

By pressing the buttons you can change the value of `playlistIndex` correctly and the UI is refreshed.

On the contrary, the loop that prints each item of the playlist does not update which one is selected, and it is using the same variable `playlistIndex`

```
                ForEach(0..<playlist.count) {
                    if $0 == self.playlistIndex {
                        Text(" \(playlist[$0].title)")
                    } else {
                        Text(playlist[$0].title)
                    }
                }
```

I was expecting ForEach to run every time @State changes, it seems that it run the first time and hold the first value of `playlistIndex`.

My question is, how can I print @State dependent loops ?

Comment: You are looping over `ForEach(0..<playlist.count)`. You should be looping over the _contents_ of `playlist`. That after all is why you made a Track an Identifiable, so that you could loop over an array _of Tracks_. You went to all that trouble and then you throw it away.

Comment: thanks for answering @matt, Yes, that was my first idea, and I left the struct identifiable.  
I used the Range to be able to access $0 the current index to be able to add the if condition, I didn't know how to have access to the index with the other approach.

Comment: OK, but if you cycle over the tracks, does that solve the problem so that the ForEach runs any time the playlist @State changes?

Comment: wow, I'm actually very surprised my code just works fine on a real device iOS 13.3
it doesn't work on the Simulator iOS 13.4 with XCode 11.4
On the simulator, the simple label does cycle the index refreshing correctly but the within the ForEach does not refresh, weird.

Comment: If you can prove that the simulator and a device give different results, you should save the world by filing a bug with Apple!

Comment: I'm new to the ecosystem, I've reported here at swift.org https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12512 I hope it's the right place, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I would have said that's wrong. It's not a language bug, it's a SwiftUI bug. Report it to http://feedbackassistant.apple.com.

Answer (score 4):

`ForEach` does not refresh, because range was not changed - SwiftUI tries to optimise redrawing by checking for equality...

Use instead like below (if your playlist item Identifiable)

```
ForEach(Array(playlist.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (i, item) in
    if i == self.playlistIndex {
        Text(" \(item.title)")
    } else {
        Text(item.title)
    }
}
```